# Any course materials on Herstein's TOPICS IN ALGEBRA, 2nd edition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, reference-request, online-resources

I'm reading the book *Topics In Algebra* by I.N. Herstein, 2nd edition, and I'm looking for course materials --- lecture notes / handouts, problem sets (with solutions), exams (with solutions), and if possible also video lectures --- of a course (or courses) taught using this book as the textbook.

Are there any such courses with materials available online, either through the course webpage(s) or through the pages of the faculty member(s)?

Any universities' mathematics departments using this book as a textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a course at Dartmouth College that follows I.N. Herstein. You can find some handouts/worksheets, problems along with their solutions. Here is the link to the course: 
https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m31f12/public_html/syl.html

Answer (score 3):

Here are some links about algebra (not HERSTEIN as source)

[Socratica Youtube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLi01XoE8jYoi3SgnnGorR_XOW3IcK-TP6)

[Juan Klopper Youtube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLsu0TcgLDUiI2VH4ubaKNLxp8O5DN9pF3)

[James Cook Youtube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBY4G2o7DhF0JCgapYKrqibGaJuvV4Gkb)

[Berkeley solved problems](https://math.berkeley.edu/~scanlon/m113f07/x1psolfin.pdf)

[AMS Book: Problems in Abstract Algebra](https://books.google.com/books?id=LafUDgAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[Abstract Algebra Manual: Problems and Solutions](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kbOC1bFs7IQC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[Exercises in Classical Ring Theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781475739879)

Caution: Don't use any Solutions book such as [Solutions to TOPICS IN ALGEBRA I.N. HERSTEIN](http://www.math.iisc.ernet.in/~rakesh13/group_theory.pdf). Instead try yourself first and second.